# c# get datasource of a datagridview from another source

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I have 2 form in my application Form1 and summary. I have a button in form1 onclick I will choose a mdb file then it gets connected to mdb. I have a datagridview in summary.

What I need is once I connect the mdb file I need to update the data (in other words set `datagrid.DataSource = ds` from Form1) so that the data from mdb shows on datagridview of summary Form

Before selecting my question as duplicate or -1 plzz make clear that database will be connected in form1 which needs to be show in summary form. I had tried all the ways shown in google but no result.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms app?

Comment: Yes I want the datagrid of summary form data to be updated once I connect the mdb in Form1

Comment: I have tried but it isn't showing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it make another constructor in summary form that have paramater like that

```
 public summary(dataset ds){
      initializecomponent();// there
  // here bind the DataSet with grid of summary
    }
```

call from form1

```
   summary obj = new summary (ds);
         obj.show();
```

Comment: Ok guys now I understood that you are not getting my question I don't need summary mate summary is the name of my another form which have datagridview in it. I have written a function in Form1 to connect to the mdb it is getting connected successfully no issues. My question is how to show the data init on my another form named as summary

Comment: Love you guys thx to all I fixed it with @zulqamain Khalil answer thx.

Comment: but in future you will face more issues so it is better to use global dataset with static property ... while making big projects

Comment: you can also acess the grid of from summary if it is in opened state from form1 using `obj.show() ; obj.datagridview1 = ds` for that goto summary form change grid modifier property to public then acess grid on form 1 so you need no new contructor

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about changing the connection string, like:

```
private SqlConnection getConn(string Initial_Catalog_Name_Of_Database)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-JHHHN0A\MLSQLSRVR16;Initial Catalog="+Initial_Catalog_Name_Of_Database+";Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=9600");
    }
```

Then

```
 private void non_Query(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandTimeout = 900;
                com.CommandText = sql;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

If that's not your question, please post your code and be more specific about what you need.

Answer (score 0):

On the Summary Form Load, Query DB and populate your DataGridView.

Use the below sample code on your Form Load.

```
string connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=your .mdb file;";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the above code. But I have the datagridview in another form called summary mate. Plz check the updated question.

Comment: To access the DataSet/DataTable between the forms, you can declare it as a global variable, so you can fill the value in Form 1 and access it from second form.

Comment: Use 'Static' keyword to make a variable global.

Comment: public static DataSet StaticData;

Comment: But how to call this global var in another form

Comment: make your Main Form as public Class
'
public class frmMain
{

}


public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _frmMain = this;
        }
public static frmMain _frmMain;
'


In the Second Form,

'
 thisSummaryForm.DGV.DataSource = frmMain.StaticData;
'

If you can post the code, its easier for everyone to help you.